# Select or substract an specific part of an element of a data frame

Tags: r

I want to get only a part of an element that is part of a data frame.

My dataframe has 1 column with 6000 rows looking like this:

```
chr5_122424840_122523745_NM_001136239_mRNA
chr17_38632079_38657854_NM_032865_mRNA
```

I want to obtain a new data frame with only

```
NM_001136239
NM_032865
```

I've tried with `split` and then `paste` but it is not working because it eliminates the zeros when pasting (NM_1136239 instead of NM_001136239)

I've also tried with `stri_sub` and `substr`but the lenght before NM is not the same in each row. Also `gsub` but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you very much for your help, I hope I've been enough specific.

Comment: Thank you very much for the edition David Arenburg, I'm new in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

***Data***

```
df <- data.frame(col=c("chr5_122424840_122523745_NM_001136239_mRNA",
                       "chr17_38632079_38657854_NM_032865_mRNA"))
```

***Code***

```
df$col <- sub(".*(NM.*)_mRNA", "\\1", df$col)
```

Just as long as the strings have `NM` and end in `_mRNA`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do. Here goes one that uses library stringr. I simply recommend it because code is easier to understand

```
library(stringr)
patron <- "NM_[0-9]+" # NM_ pasted to any number of digits
str_extract(your_data_frame$your_column, patron) # Assign to a column or not
```